# Spyder: Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console, An error occured see the console error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I had converted azureml dataset into python dataframe
but spyder is unable to show me the dataframe. Kindly help

[image]

Comment: Usually `see the console` means that you should look there...

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same error. I found the answer in these posts: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15998 and https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15998.

You need to downgrade pandas to version 1.3.5:
`conda install pandas==1.3.5`

Answer (score 0):

This problem has plagued me for such a long time. I found a simple solution.

Here is my basic environment:

**Spyder Environment**

Spyder, version 5.4.5

Python, version 3.10.4

**Working Environment**

Spyder-Kernels, version 2.4.4

Python, version 3.11.7

Pandas, version 2.1.4

If you read through the github issues thread link below, you will learn that when you call an variable through the variable explorer, that variable type must be supported by the environment that Spyder is installed in. So, this means if you are having trouble opening up a dataframe in Spyder, then it is likely that Pandas wasn't installed in your Spyder environment.

Run `conda install pandas` in your Spyder environment, then restart Spyder. Your finished! Of course, if your having trouble with a different data type, then you need to install the correct package for that class.

GitHub thread here:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15998